# Мониторинг сетевой активности процессов

Tags: linux, сеть, взлом

Один из серверов, как говорит хостинг провайдер - взломан. Сервер шлёт **2-4 Гб** данных на 80 порт UDP, китайский ip. Это наш заббикс сервер и он открыт снаружи и иногда может слать какие-то данные на внешние ип других серверов, хотя преимущественно работаем через VPN. ОДНАКО не в Китай, там у нас нет ни одного сервера.

Как отследить какой из процессов проявляет сетевую активность, желательно упорядочить данные по объёму трафика и чтобы лог писался круглосуточно, с возможностью затем его прочесть.
Может `netstat` обладает такой возможностью?
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Для мониторинга сети, лично я, предпочитаю использовать:

- [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) для реал-тайм монитора. Легкий и информативный.
- [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/netatop.php) для логирования и анализа, при использовании модуля `netatop`, можно вести учет сети в разрезе процессов.
- [sysdig falco](https://habrahabr.ru/company/selectel/blog/309188/) очень полезная штука для мониторинга системы в плане безопасности.
  Но если система скомпрометирована, то бозоговорочно доверять системным утилитам запущенным на ней не стоит: руткит может пытаться скрыть сетевую активность, да и сами утилиты могут быть патченные. В таком случае трафик лучше мониторить и анализировать на шлюзе или файерволле через который он проходит.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ!

Как оказалось, malware не подменил основные системные утилиты за счёт чего и удалось его обнаружить. Подозрительное подключение к `198.55.114.237:12345`
Процесс инициировавший его -- /tmp/hh, в той же папке /tmp/gates.lod c PID процесса. 
Дальше немного погуглив нашлась [статья](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/state-of-the-internet/bill-gates-botnet-threat-advisory.pdf) описывающая виды такого вируса. Как он работает, как его удалить.